# Why is my channel closed whenever I send the data

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I have my code below

```
interface Listener {
    fun onGetData(data: Int)
    fun onClose()
}

class MyEmitter {
    var listener: Listener? = null
    fun sendData(data: Int) = listener?.onGetData(data)
    fun close() = listener?.onClose()
}

fun handleInput(myEmitter: MyEmitter) = channelFlow {
    myEmitter.listener = object:Listener {
        override fun onGetData(data: Int) { trySend(data) }
        override fun onClose() { close() }
    }
}

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val myEmitter = MyEmitter()
    
    handleInput(myEmitter).collect {
        println(it)
    }

    myEmitter.sendData(1)
    myEmitter.sendData(2)
    myEmitter.close()
}
```

Whenever I send the data e.g. `myEmitter.sendData(1)`, it does get into `trySend(data)`, but the result is `closed`.

Why is it closed? How can I keep it open?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not documented terribly clearly, but just like the `flow` builder, the `channelFlow`'s Flow is considered complete once the suspend lambda returns. Since all you are doing is setting a listener and not waiting around, it will return almost immediately. When a channel Flow is completed, it's channel is also closed.

If you want your `channelFlow` to stay open until the Flow is canceled, call `awaitClose()` at the end. This function suspends until the channel is closed, so it will hold your Flow open until it's canceled or the event in your listener closes the Channel.

```
fun handleInput(myEmitter: MyEmitter) = channelFlow {
    myEmitter.listener = object:Listener {
        override fun onGetData(data: Int) { trySend(data) }
        override fun onClose() { close() }
    }
    awaitClose()
}
```

If you are familiar with `callbackFlow`, it is a specialized version of `channelFlow` and it enforces the `awaitClose()` call because it is meant for waiting for a listener, so there's no reason you would ever *not* want to await. It's also where you can deregister any listener you created inside the flow builder.

Comment: Thanks. In my original design, I do have `awaitClose() { myEmitter.listener = null }`, but when I run it, it just hangs there. I guess is the runBlocking causing the problem there?

Comment: @Elye yes, `runBlocking` will wait for all child coroutines to complete before it returns.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working, I did 3 things

1. Add `awaitClose` to ensure the flow is not terminated
2. Move the entire flow behind `launch`, so that it is not blocking the `main()` function flow
3. Add a little `delay` before `myEmitter.sendData(1)`, so that to ensure the `launch` get triggered first before doing the external `sendData`.

Full changed code as below

```
interface Listener {
    fun onGetData(data: Int)
    fun onClose()
}

class MyEmitter {
    var listener: Listener? = null
    fun sendData(data: Int) = listener?.onGetData(data)
    fun close() = listener?.onClose()
}

fun handleInput(myEmitter: MyEmitter) = channelFlow {
    myEmitter.listener = object:Listener {
        override fun onGetData(data: Int) { trySend(data) }
        override fun onClose() { close() }
    }
    awaitClose { myEmitter.listener = null } // Need awaitClose to keep the flow alive
}

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val myEmitter = MyEmitter()

    launch { // Need to run to avoid it from blocking the main() function flow due to having `awaitClose` there
        handleInput(myEmitter).collect {
            println(it)
        }
    }

    delay(100) // Add some delay to get this triggered after the launch run
    myEmitter.sendData(1)
    myEmitter.sendData(2)
    myEmitter.close()
}
```

The 3rd step is a little hack I think.

Comment: Try wrapping everything inside `runBlocking` with `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` instead of launching a child coroutine. I’m away from computer so I can’t try it, but maybe that would resolve the single threaded issue without the hack.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I try replace `launch` with `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`, but doesn't work.